# Kafka Connector always works as a single task

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

[image]

I am trying to transfer data from oracleDB to mongoDB using kafka. 
So I configured the kafka cluster like the picture above.
I know that adjusting partition and tasks.max allows parallel processing. 
However, when I run the connector, it always runs as a single task and cannot be processed in parallel.
Are there any additional settings I need to do?

Here is what I configured.

1. Topic creation

> bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server
>   127.0.0.1:9092,127.0.0.2:9092,127.0.0.1:9093 --partitions 3 --topic topicA

2. connector config

   ```
   {
   "name": "rawsumc-source",
   "config": {
       "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
       "connection.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521/orcl",
       "connection.user": "test",
       "connection.password": "test",
       "topic.prefix": "topicA",
       "mode": "bulk",
       "poll.interval.ms": "360000000",
       "numeric.mapping": "best_fit",
       "tasks.max": "10",
       "connection.type": "lz4",
       "query": "select CAST(NO_TT AS NUMBER(10,0)) AS NO_TT,CAST(NO_SEQ AS NUMBER(10,0)) AS NO_SEQ,DNT_CLCT from table_a",
       "name": "rawsumc-source"
   },
   "tasks": [
       {
           "connector": "rawsumc-source",
           "task": 0
       }
   ],
   "type": "source"}
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the [docs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing/configuring.html#connect-managing-config-connectors):

> `tasks.max` - The **maximum** number of tasks that should be created for this connector. The connector may create *fewer* tasks if it cannot achieve this level of parallelism.

Using a custom query for JdbcSourceConnector [limits](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/blob/f0021c5c4924ff383b7f57b9f919f2009051146f/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/jdbc/JdbcSourceConnector.java#L141-L145) you to a single task.

Comment: Alexander thank you for your response. But when I tested without custom query, it works as a single task too.
There is two workers in connector cluster up and running, and topic partition is three.

Comment: I am trying with just one table. "table.whitelist": "TA_TEST"

Comment: It’s ok since for table mode real number of tasks is minimum of max.tasks and tables count. Please check [sources](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/blob/f0021c5c4924ff383b7f57b9f919f2009051146f/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/jdbc/JdbcSourceConnector.java#L152)

Comment: This was the solution for me, too. removing `tasks.max` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also confused about this connetor tasks.
At first I thought **kafka connect** solved the problem of multiple client data duplication. But in fact **kafka connect** chose other ways to avoid this problem. I tracked the source code and found its actual implementation.

(I can't post images now, you can click the link to see the image.)
firstly it's the taskConfigs interface:
[taskConfigs interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mc9mz.png)

```
    /**
 * Returns a set of configurations for Tasks based on the current configuration,
 * producing at most count configurations.
 *
 * @param maxTasks maximum number of configurations to generate
 * @return configurations for Tasks
 */
public abstract List<Map<String, String>> taskConfigs(int maxTasks);
```

then its' the call for this interface:
[call for this interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6W0S.png)

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:
  final List<Map<String, String>> taskProps = worker.connectorTaskConfigs(connName, connConfig);
        boolean changed = false;
        int currentNumTasks = configState.taskCount(connName);
        if (taskProps.size() != currentNumTasks) {
            log.debug("Change in connector task count from {} to {}, writing updated task configurations", currentNumTasks, taskProps.size());
            changed = true;
        }
```

how kafka connect use task props:
[how kafka connect use task props](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9NXh.png)

```
if (changed) {
            List<Map<String, String>> rawTaskProps = reverseTransform(connName, configState, taskProps);
            if (isLeader()) {
                configBackingStore.putTaskConfigs(connName, rawTaskProps);
                cb.onCompletion(null, null);
            }
```

This means kafka connect use the task configs to create the internal threads.
So how many tasks running is determined by the connector implementation on  taskConfigs  method.

Let's see  the implementation on mqtt source connector:
[implementation on mqtt source connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7Lbz.png)

```
   public List<Map<String, String>> taskConfigs(int maxTasks) {
 List<Map<String, String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
 int taskId = 0;
 for (List<String> mqttTopics : (Iterable<List<String>>)ConnectorUtils.groupPartitions(this.config.mqttTopics, maxTasks)) {
   if (mqttTopics.isEmpty())
     continue; 
   Map<String, String> settings = new LinkedHashMap<>(this.settings);
   settings.put("mqtt.topics", Joiner.on(',').join(mqttTopics));
   settings.put("task.id", Integer.toString(taskId++));
   result.add(settings);
 } 
 return result;
```

}
This tasks is grouped by the mqtt topics.
Actually I just declared one topic filter, so I always got one mqtt source task.**How many tasks will be running is determined by the taskConfigs method implementation on your connector, input is the max tasks from connector configs..**
You may read the source code implementation on your connector for this method..